# Is there a way to set the extent parameter of a bin dynamically (histogram)?

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite

I'm using vega-lite in PBI and I'm trying to create a histogram in which its X-axis range changes dynamically acording to two fields (Start, End) from a table of my PBI, this two fields repeat in each record as can be seen in image.

[PBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imbWd.png)

The examples of extent in the documentation I found used only numbers, so my initial code is this:

[initial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzK6A.png)

Yet I'm trying to do following code:

```
{
"data": {"name": "dataset"},
"mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "tooltip": true
},
"encoding": {
    "x": {
        "bin": {
            "extent": [
                {"field": "Start"},
                {"field": "End"}
            ],
            "step": 1
        },
        "field": "Actual"
    },
    "y": {"aggregate": "count"}
}
```

}

But it throws a lot of warnings, and in the end it does nothing:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znm1E.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting bin extent based on field name is not supported. Per the [Vega-lite docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bin.html#bin-parameters), bin.range is

> A two-element ([min, max]) array indicating the range of desired bin values.

where min and max are each numbers.

As to your specific use-case: I would suggest filtering out the data points that fall outside the range you want to ignore. [filter docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/filter.html).

Your filter might look something like this (this will drop all points outside of the extent you specified)

```
{
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
         "not": {"field": "Actual", "range": [25, 45]} } 
       }
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

If you need [25, 45] to be dynamic, you can set them using an [ExprRef](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/predicate.html#range-predicate) instead of using a number, like this

```
"range": [
   {"expr": "datum.Start"},
   {"expr": "datum.End"}
]
```